# Integration without $\sup$ (or $\inf$)?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I teach high-school calculus and am wondering:

Might it be possible to define some simple but fully rigorous version of integration without using $\sup$ (or $\inf$)? Perhaps by imposing strong assumptions such as continuity (and possibly other concepts that high-school students may be familiar with)?

Has anyone already done something like this?

Comment: but you'll still need lim ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yes that will be fine.

Comment: I asked a moderator to migrate this to Mathematics Educators SE

Answer (score 1):

I think high school students can deal with summation. How about trying to introduce Riemann sums? It's quite intuitive (summing areas), and if you're dealing with continuous functions then you don't really need $limsup$; just limits are "good enough".